# eslint giving false positive

Tags: typescript, webpack, eslint

I'm new to Webpack and have ran into an issue with eslint and Typescript. eslint is telling me that I'm missing return type on functions, but as you can see I have one.

I have include the `@typescript-eslint/parser` in my .eslintrc file

```
// test-function.ts
7  function numberOne(): number {
8    return 1;
9  }
10    
11 const numberTwo = (): number => 2;
12    
13 console.log( numberTwo() - numberOne() );
```

```
// webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');

const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  mode: 'development',
  watch: false,
  entry: path.join( __dirname, 'src', 'index.ts'),
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: [
          /node_modules/,
          /declarations/
        ],
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'eslint-loader',
            options: {
              configFile: '.eslintrc.json',
              cache: false,
              emitError: true,
              failOnError: true,
              fix: true
            }
          }
          ,
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
              transpileOnly: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin(),
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist')
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.wasm', '.ts', '.tsx', '.mjs', '.cjs', '.js', '.json']
  }
};
```

```
// .eslintrc
{
  "root": true,
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "project": "./tsconfig.json"
  },
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true,
    "worker": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking"
  ],
  "ignorePatterns": [],
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": ["error"]
  }
}
```

This is what the error looks like

```
   7:1   warning  Missing return type on function           @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type
  10:19  warning  Missing return type on function           @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the line number of your codes?

Comment: @troy Just update with line numbers hope this helps.